# How do you pass data out of a React component using a callback?

Tags: reactjs, state, react-datepicker, react-hook-form

I'm new to React and my first project involves creating a form (created with [react-hook-form](https://react-hook-form.com/)) which includes date pickers (using [React Datepicker](https://reactdatepicker.com/)). Everything's working fine so far except my date picker which when clicked does not update the form field with the new selected date.

The project is structured as follows:

```
index.js 
   V
Form.js
   V
ChooseInputType.js (this is looking at a json file of the form questions and choosing what form input to display)
   V
FormDate.js (A date picker will be shown if the json file says it's a date field).
```

**FormDate.js**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import DatePicker from 'react-datepicker';
import 'react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css';
import { Controller } from 'react-hook-form';
function FormDate({ name, question, register, control, type }) {
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date());
  return (
    <div className="form-group">
      <label htmlFor={name}>{question}</label>
      <div className="input-group date col-xs-5">
        <Controller
          as={
            <DatePicker
              selected={startDate}
              onChange={date => setStartDate(date)}
              selectsStart
              startDate={startDate}
            />
          }
          control={control}
          name={name}
          ref={register}
          id={name}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
export default FormDate;
```

I have used the Controller component as per the [react-hook-form Controller documentation](https://react-hook-form.com/advanced-usage/#ConditionalControlledComponent) as I will eventually need to use conditional logic and thought that was the right thing to do? But other than that it appears to be the same as the [date range sample code](https://reactdatepicker.com/#example-date-range). I've received a hint from someone elsewhere that the issue is as follows:

> The issue is the Controller component that you have your date pickers
>   wrapped in. They are consuming the onChange callback and not allowing
>   it to propagate the child component.
>
> From reading the documentation you can only use uncontrolled
>   components within them, things like html  tags, anything that
>   requires React to directly manipulate their state will function here.
>
> You’ll have to look at passing the data you require from the form
>   elements, like your date pickers, back up to your main form and
>   compiling what you need to be submitted there manually. You can pass
>   data back out of components using either callbacks, React.context or
>   some other global state management system like Redux. Personally, I’d
>   recommend sticking to callbacks whilst the complexity of the app is
>   still manageable and only look at the other options if things start to
>   get really complicated.

Is anyone able to help me (as a noob!) understand how to do this, perhaps with an example? Or is there any documentation that might help me out?

Many thanks,

Katie

Comment: can you take a look this example: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-controller-079xx

Comment: Amazing Bill! I didn't think I would ever get a response, but this is perfect. I've amended my code and will post what it looks like below. Thank you ever so much for this!

Answer (score 1):

Following Bill's answer in the comments attached to my original question, I have amended my code to look like this and it now updates the date field inside the Controller! Thanks Bill. Bill has also included examples of how you would use the Controller with many different types inputs, so please give him a thank you if you find that useful.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDatePicker from 'react-datepicker'; 
import 'react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css';
import { Controller } from 'react-hook-form';
function FormDate({ name, question, register, control}) {
  return (
    <div className="form-group">
      <label htmlFor={name}>{question}</label>
      <div className="input-group date col-xs-5">
        <Controller
          as={
            <DatePicker
              dateFormat="dd/MM/yyyy"
              placeHolderText="Select date"
              className="input"
            />
          }
          control={control}
          name={name}
          ref={register}
          id={name}
          valueName="selected" //This is key!
          onChange={([selected]) => selected} //This is key!
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
export default FormDate;
```

I wanted to format the date and this is a [useful list of props that you can pass into the date picker component](https://github.com/Hacker0x01/react-datepicker/blob/master/docs/datepicker.md)

Thanks again Bill - your examples are a fantastic help!